# Strip after a "." from input value

Tags: javascript, strip

I have this script that is changing the value of an input field.

The output I want is like: A-Z. (A. and B. end so on)

How can I achieve that everything after the "." is being stripped.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function hoofdlettermetpunt(obj)
    {
        var firstChar = document.all(obj).value.charAt(0);
        firstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase() + ".";
        document.all(obj).value = document.all(obj).value.replace(
                                  document.all(obj).value.charAt(0), firstChar);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: some example input strings would be useful, as in examples of what would be typed into the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip anything away after a dot `.` from a string you can use the following:

```
var str = 'My test. string';
var newstr = str.split('.',2)[0];

/// newstr will contain 'My test'
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your code to actually answer your question in terms of your example however. Basically `.split` will always return an array so you can use `[0]` as an array access straight afterwards - which will give you the first found element in the array *(which because of the split, will be the substring you want)*. The above will work even if the string doesn't contain a `.`.

For information about `.split()` see below:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Javascript, but you really want to return the substring of everything up to the beginning of the string, but not including the character at the index of the substring.

```
return s.subString(indexOf('.')) // You may need to add a -1 to offset the location of the substring.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve that everything after the "." is being stripped?

Try:

```
String str = "Hello.Whose this !!!";

String[] tempArr = str.split("\\.");

String finalVal = tempArr[0];       // Hello is obtained
```

Comment: @pimvdb Ohh by mistake i gave the answer in wrong section... i thought its with java tags... sorry.. `But i think this will still work.`